# How to style a Fabrik (Joomla) form?

Tags: joomla-3.x, css, fabrik, style

I'm new in the joomla world and I don't know very well how to style a form created with fabrik, I don't know where to add the styles or anything.
If you can guide me it would be of great help.

Thanks in advance to all of you!

Comment: Welcome to JSE. Please take our [tour]. I'm going to remove some unnecessary text from your question.  After that, please [edit] your question to include links to online resources that you found while visiting.  These details 1. Give context 2. Help future researchers to find related reading and 3. Indicates to contributors that you have invested time and effort before asking for help.  This community is 100% volunteer, so please make your question(s) as simple, narrow, and attractive to answer as you can.

Comment: I role model these same behaviours when I ask for help -- even on StackOverflow where I have been a contributor for many years.  I show all of my effort, respect those who offer support, and try to make my problem as small as possible.  My most recent example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69609482/2943403